# Blender 2.8 python - Add Texture Image

Tags: python, texturing, materials, image, color

I've been attempting to create a meterial, and add different textures to the properties using a script. I am testing with just a diffuse/color first, but am having trouble getting it to work.

I've tried various posts' answers, and even [Blender 2.8 documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.node.html#bpy.ops.node.add_file) and they all throw errors.

Blender code:

```
`bpy.ops.node.add_file(filepath="C:\Users\myName\Downloads\Textures\Downloaded\flooring5.jpg", filter_blender=False, filter_backup=False, filter_image=True, filter_movie=True, filter_python=False, filter_font=False, filter_sound=False, filter_text=False, filter_btx=False, filter_collada=False, filter_alembic=False, filter_folder=True, filter_blenlib=False, filemode=9, relative_path=True, show_multiview=False, use_multiview=False, display_type='DEFAULT', sort_method='FILE_SORT_ALPHA', name="Image")`
```

My Error:

```
location: <unknown location>:-1
Error:   File "C:\Users\nmaestre\Desktop\Projects\TextureShapes\TextureMesh.blend\Text", line 48
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Pic for ref
[image: TextureIssuesPython]

Current Working Code: (i found this from another post)

```
#Import python
import bpy

# Clear all nodes in a mat
def clear_material( material ):
    if material.node_tree:
        material.node_tree.links.clear()
        material.node_tree.nodes.clear()


# Create a node corresponding to a defined group
def instanciate_group( nodes, group_name ):
    group = nodes.new( type = 'ShaderNodeGroup' )
    group.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups[group_name]


#ref materials  
materials = bpy.data.materials
#name material
mat_name = 'Mat_Tile'
# get ref to material
material = materials.get( mat_name )

#if not our mat
if not material:
    material = materials.new( mat_name )

# We clear it as we'll define it completely
clear_material( material )

material.use_nodes = True

nodes = material.node_tree.nodes
links = material.node_tree.links

output = nodes.new( type = 'ShaderNodeOutputMaterial' )

diffuse = nodes.new( type = 'ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse' )

#input = nodes.new( type = 'ShaderNodeTexImage')

#With names
link = links.new( diffuse.outputs['BSDF'], output.inputs['Surface'])
#Or with indices
#link = links.new( diffuse.outputs[0], output.inputs[0] )
```

Comment: If you want to use backslashes in the path, you need to escape them by adding another backslash.

Comment: You are correct!

Answer (score 5):

I found a combination of other user's code with some debugging to get a working solution for now.

```
#Import python
import bpy
from bpy import context, data, ops


mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="New_Mat")
mat.use_nodes = True
bsdf = mat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
texImage = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
texImage.image = bpy.data.images.load("C:\\Users\\myName\\Downloads\\Textures\\Downloaded\\flooring5.jpg")
mat.node_tree.links.new(bsdf.inputs['Base Color'], texImage.outputs['Color'])

ob = context.view_layer.objects.active

# Assign it to object
if ob.data.materials:
    ob.data.materials[0] = mat
else:
    ob.data.materials.append(mat)
```