# How can I replace image texture, save a render then repeat for all images in a folder from Python?

Tags: python, texturing, scripting

I have a 3D product and need to render it out a couple of times, each time with a different label. I was hoping there was a way to automate this.

I found a [script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157531/blender-2-8-python-add-texture-image) to load an image texture but need some help making it load all images in a folder and saving a render for each one.

The code so far for 1 image:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context, data, ops


mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="labels")
mat.use_nodes = True
bsdf = mat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
texImage = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
texImage.image = bpy.data.images.load("/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Lab/blenderScripting/kingfisher/psdtest/Label2.jpg")
mat.node_tree.links.new(bsdf.inputs['Base Color'], texImage.outputs['Color'])

ob = context.view_layer.objects.active

# Assign it to object
if ob.data.materials:
    ob.data.materials[0] = mat
else:
    ob.data.materials.append(mat)
```

Comment: A simple solution is to rename all your textures to something like "tex0001.png", "tex0002.png", etc. And then select "Image Sequence" in the ImageTexture node.

Comment: @Secrop that’s genius.

Comment: Ah yes, I sometimes forget about the simple solutions. Will give it a try. Thanks @Secrop